# see air temperature on dell m3800 laptop

Tags: windows, temperature, dell-precision

The specs say my Dell Precision M3800 has an air temperature sensor.

I can't find any way to read the value. Is there a way that can be accessed from within windows?

Comment: You might see if [speedfan](http://www.almico.com/forummotherboards.php?man=265) can read the sensor ...

Comment: @DavidPostill, can you provide a download link? The one I found went to malware.

Comment: http://www.almico.com/speedfan452.exe works for me ...

Comment: @DavidPostill, yeah I get a virus warning on that one. My pc was infected last week so I'm reluctant to make an exception esp. since that website looks so ... unpolished. but thanks!

Comment: @toddmo - The website David linked you to is the official Speedfan website.  Your security software is clearly throwing a false postive.  In any event the Speedfan exectuable is signed by its author, that is how you know, it is the official verison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Dell [manual](http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/precision-m3800-workstation_owner's%20manual_en-us.pdf) I can't find a reference to an air temperature sensor as you describe.

Normally there are sensors on the motherboard to monitor the internal temperature of components such as the CPU and graphics card. Normally these aren't accessible to users but software like [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php) mentioned by @DavidPostill can show the temperatures.

Depending on system load these temperatures can range from 30C up to 80C. I have attached a screenshot of my system.

[image: Screenshot of SpeedFan]